# how to show items grid view in alert dialog in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview

```
/**
 * Loads [MainFragment].
 */
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {
//    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    private var player: ExoPlayer? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//                .replace(R.id.main_browse_fragment, MainFragment())
//                .commitNow()
            initializePlayer()
            findViewById<Button>(R.id.language).setOnClickListener{
                customDialoug()
            }

        }
    }
 private fun customDialoug() {
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        alertDialog.setTitle("Choose Language")
        val items = arrayOf("Hindi", "English", "Tamil", "Telgu", "Punjabi","Bengali")
        val checkedItem = 1
        alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(items, checkedItem, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
            when (which) {
                0 -> Toast.makeText(this, items.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                1 -> Toast.makeText(this, items.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                2 -> Toast.makeText(this, items.get(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                3 -> Toast.makeText(this, items.get(3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                4 -> Toast.makeText(this, items.get(4), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                5 -> Toast.makeText(this, items.get(5), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })


        // on below line we are setting adapter to our grid view.

        val alert = alertDialog.create()
        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        alert.show()

    }
```

`

this is my code it is working but i want to show the items in grid view,how can i do that without using recycler view and all those stuff, is there any way by adding few lines of code the items will visible in grid view
this is my code it is working but i want to show the items in grid view,how can i do that without using recycler view and all those stuff, is there any way by adding few lines of code the items will visible in grid view
this is my code it is working but i want to show the items in grid view,how can i do that without using recycler view and all those stuff, is there any way by adding few lines of code the items will visible in grid view